# Installing postfix hangs at Postfix Configuration Screen?

Tags: linux, postfix, installation

I am trying to install postfix on a newly build Ubuntu 8.04 on a Dell R200.  When I start the install process

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

I get stuck at the following screen
[image]

The session becomes non-responsive, enter / ctrl-c ... no response

Any ideas how to get past this hangup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know it might sound silly but connect to that machine over some ssh client ( from linux in x from graphical terminal or via putty in windows ) and enlarge the window. as i remember in this dialog there is combo below where you select desired configuration.

Comment: I went to full screen on putty and it worked correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I found an easier solution. press TAB and then the OK will be highlighted. Press Enter and you will be able to see the list

Comment: I had this problem and TAB worked for me - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a different workaround that was much easier (especially since I didn't have a machine ready to do the remote ssh session already) and thought I'd post it here in case others run into this issue.

I don't know how to do this on any Linux distro, but on my Ubuntu 9.1 environment, I changed the terminal window "resolution" via the Termimal menu to 132x43 prior to issuing the postfix install command and was able to see the complete configuration "window" correctly and was able to finish the installation without a ssh remote session.